# how do i import beautifulsoup4 in Pycharm?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

[i installed bs4 through terminal(pip3 install beautifulsoup4), and as i typed 'from bs4 import beaufitulsoup' it seemed to work but it turns out not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYbQp.png)

[how can i solve this problem?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs1Lh.png)

i installed bs4 through terminal(pip3 install beautifulsoup4), and as i typed 'from bs import beaufitulsoup4' it seemed to work but it turns out not. how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You must include the method names from `bs4` and not the whole library. `bs4` is the module name for `BeautifulSoup4` library. We usually import its method `BeautifulSoup` and not the library name `BeautifulSoup4`. Also, there is a spelling mistake in your import statement.
The following statements would work fine.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

And

```
from bs4 import *
```